# EE5: How to create or update entries in a custom made module

Tags: module, ee5

In EE2 I used the channel entries API to create and update entries. In EE5 I can't use it anymore. The only problem is that I can't find any EE5 API functions to create those entries. Are they gone?

How can I create/update entries in EE5 without using the the legacy channel entries API? I can't find it in de docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this:

```
$entry = ee('Model')->make('ChannelEntry', $data);
$entry -> save();
```

Just make sure you have all the required info in the $data array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and update the Channel Entry using below **Model query**.

**For Creating the Entry :-**

```
$entry = ee('Model')->make('ChannelEntry');
$entry->Channel = $channel;
$entry->site_id =  ee()->config->item('site_id');
$entry->author_id = ee()->session->userdata('member_id');
$entry->ip_address = ee()->session->userdata['ip_address'];
$entry->versioning_enabled = $channel->enable_versioning;
$entry->sticky = FALSE;
$entry->title = $title_url_title;
$entry->url_title = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $title_url_title);
$entry->entry_date = ee()->localize->now;
$entry->edit_date = ee()->localize->now;
$entry->save();

/* Array which contains your Field Data */
$entry->set($entryFieldArray);
```

**For Updating the Entry :-**

```
$entry = ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry', $id)
        ->with('Channel')
        ->filter('site_id', ee()->config->item('site_id'))
        ->first();

/* Array which contains your Field Data which need to update */
$entry->set($entryFieldArray);
```

Comment: awesome! I never know I had to use the Model service. Thanks for the tip!